# How to use Ember compiled layouts with a default

Tags: ember.js

I have the need for two application templates. I thought I could solve this using layouts.

All apart from one route and view use one layout and the index route/view uses another. I want to avoid manually creating Ember.View objects if it's not necessary.

So:

```
Ember.View.layoutName = 'layouts/app';

App.IndexView = Ember.View.extend({
    layoutName: 'layouts/logged-out'
});
```

The intention here was to set the default layout used by all views to `'layouts/app'` which is compiled from a handlebars file using grunt and ends up in the `Ember.TEMPLATES` array as per the regular templates.

The layouts are basically structured like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="thirteen wide column">
        {{ yield }}
    </div>
</div>
```

At the moment the layout html is ignored completely and it only renders what was in the template.

So the question is, if this is the right approach what am I missing to make it work? And if it's not the right approach, what should I be doing instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your only problem is with the property definition, you need to use `reopen`, to set a default instance property, instead of `Ember.View.layoutName = 'layouts/app';`.

In your case:

```
Ember.View.reopen({
  layoutName: 'layouts/app'
});
```